# Select bitmap object failed

Tags: python, automation, printing

I am creating this app in python that does automated scheduled printing of an image on a printer. When I try to print, it gives me this error.
Error printing image: Select bitmap object failed

Following is my printing function:

```
def print_image(image_path, printer_name)
    try:
       win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(printer_name)
       new_printer = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
       img = Image.open(image_path)

       # Create a device context for the printer
       h_dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
       h_dc.CreatePrinterDC(new_printer)

       # Start the printing process
       h_dc.StartDoc("Print Job")
       h_dc.StartPage()

       # Get the printer's printable area (in pixels)
       printer_info = get_printer_info(new_printer)
       physical_width = printer_info["pDevMode"].PaperWidth

       # Calculate the aspect ratio
       aspect_ratio = img.size[0] / img.size[1]

       # Calculate the new size to fit the image within the printable area
       new_width = int(physical_width * 0.9)
       new_height = int(new_width / aspect_ratio)

       # Resize the image to fit the printable area
       img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), resample= Image.LANCZOS)

       # Convert the PIL image to a bitmap for BitBlt
       bmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
       bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(h_dc, new_width, new_height)
       h_dc.SelectObject(bmp)

       # Print the image
       img_print_info = img.convert("RGB").tobytes("raw", "RGB")
       h_dc.BitBlt((0, 0), new_width, new_height, img_print_info, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)

       # End the printing process
       h_dc.EndPage()
       h_dc.EndDoc()

       messagebox.showinfo("Print", "Image printed successfully.")
   except Exception as e:
       messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Error printing image: {e}")
```

and there is no other method to print the image that I can think of now.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.